# prevent jQuery validation messages until submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I just want to hide all the error message during and after typing the field (wrong input or empty field). And once the submit/button pressed then the message will all appear/visible.

The problem is... every time I typed wrong or I leave the text field empty it always shows the error message such "this fields is required", etc.

```
rules : {

    "user.firstname" : {
    required : true,
    maxlength: 50,

},
messsages : {
required : "required",
maxlength: "the max-length is 50"
"
}
```

Comment: You have a stray `"` in your code.

Comment: Perhaps you can please come back and let us know how this all turned out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As per [online documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), you need to use the `onfocusout:` and `onkeyup:` options.

---

> Validate elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur. If
>   nothing is entered, all rules are skipped, except when the field was
>   already marked as invalid.

This *disables* onblur validation:

```
onfocusout: false
```

---

> Validate elements on keyup. As long as the field is not marked as
>   invalid, nothing happens. Otherwise, all rules are checked on each key
>   up event.

This *disables* onkeyup validation:

```
onkeyup: false
```

---

And depending on if you have checkboxes and radio buttons, you may want to disable the `onclick:` option as well.

> Validate checkboxes and radio buttons on click.

This *disables* onclick validation:

```
onclick: false
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of $(document).ready(function(){} you can try using

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(event) {
 // Do your validation, if it fails use event.preventDefault();  
});
```

just give it a try let me know what happens...

Comment: This the wrong way to implement the plugin.  `.validate()` must be initialized inside the `document.ready` to function properly.  The click handler is already built into the plugin, so wrapping it inside another is redundant and improper.

Comment: If that's what the documentation say's then I am sorry ...but I just tried it and it works fine so can you just let me know what do you mean when you say function properly? (just out of curiosity to know)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935963/jquery-validation-messages-only-show-up-after-multiple-submits/9936025#9936025), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067999/jquery-validation-plugin-wont-validate-when-in-click-event-handler-of/11068130#11068130), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825290/jquery-validation-validate-several-time-a-field-in-a-hidden-area/10825498#10825498).  Based on the numbers of people reporting problems with your proposed implementation, it seems to be very popular, albeit totally wrong.

Comment: And this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609567/how-do-i-get-my-jquery-validator-code-to-run-a-second-time-after-a-form-has-alre/10609871#10609871

Comment: hmmm got it ..so its about the submit handler that messes up ...thanks

Comment: Yes, the plugin's `submitHandler:` is already capturing the `click` event from the `submit` button.  Also, while inside your `click` handler, it's not initialized until the click.  Then things get weird if it's clicked a second time because the plugin is unnecessarily re-initialized.